# Having issues with my weather data java program in eclipse

Tags: java

I am trying to get the code to calculate the windchill, but it is not working. I want the calculations to appear on a separate window when they are done.

In addition I need the program to have a separate error dialog box appear when invalid data is entered or when a wind chill is not valid, and the text in the GUI should reflect the issue. And the file entry button when selected, should display a file selection window. File opening errors will be handled with exceptions and dialog boxes. If the file is valid and opened successfully, the program will read in the data, compute the results, and display the data and results in columns in a separate window created through a separate class and Java file, and plot the Temperature and Wind Chill values.

Code:

```
   import java.awt.BorderLayout;
   import java.awt.EventQueue;

   import javax.swing.JFrame;
   import javax.swing.JPanel;
   import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
   import java.awt.Color;
   import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
   import javax.swing.JLabel;
   import java.awt.FlowLayout;
   import java.awt.Font;
   import java.util.Scanner;

   import javax.swing.JTextField;
   import javax.swing.JButton;
   import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
   import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

   public class WindChillCalculations extends JFrame {

   private JPanel contentPane;
   private static JTextField Fahrenheit_textField;
   private static JTextField Mph_textField;
   private static JTextField DewPoint_textField;

   /**
   * Launch the application.
   */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           try {
               WindChillCalculations frame = new WindChillCalculations();
               frame.setVisible(true);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
    });

   String fahrenheit = Fahrenheit_textField.getText();
   String speed = Mph_textField.getText();
   String dewpoint = DewPoint_textField.getText();

   double t = Double.parseDouble(fahrenheit);
   double v = Double.parseDouble(speed);
   double d = Double.parseDouble(dewpoint);

   //Calculate windchill
   double w = 35.74 + (0.6215 * t) - (35.75 * (Math.pow(v,0.16))) + (0.4275 * (t * (Math.pow(v,0.16))));

   //Format to keep the windchill to 2 digits after decimal
   w = (int)(w*100)/100.0;
 }

 /**
 * Create the frame.
 */
 public WindChillCalculations() {
   setTitle("Weather Data Program - Wind Chill Calculations");
   setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   setBounds(100, 100, 491, 383);
   contentPane = new JPanel();
   contentPane.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
   contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
   contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
   setContentPane(contentPane);
   contentPane.setLayout(null);

   JPanel panel = new JPanel();
   panel.setToolTipText("");
   panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.WHITE));
   panel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
   panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
   panel.setBounds(2, 4, 470, 338);
   contentPane.add(panel);
   panel.setLayout(null);

   JLabel WindChillCalculationsLabel = new JLabel("Wind Chill Calculations");
   WindChillCalculationsLabel.setBounds(146, 6, 137, 15);
   WindChillCalculationsLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
   panel.add(WindChillCalculationsLabel);
   WindChillCalculationsLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

   JLabel Fahrenheit_Label = new JLabel("Enter the temperature in degrees Fahrenheit:");
   Fahrenheit_Label.setForeground(new Color(255, 140, 0));
   Fahrenheit_Label.setBounds(10, 67, 305, 14);
   panel.add(Fahrenheit_Label);

   Fahrenheit_textField = new JTextField();
   Fahrenheit_textField.setBounds(338, 64, 86, 20);
   panel.add(Fahrenheit_textField);
   Fahrenheit_textField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
   Fahrenheit_textField.setColumns(10);

   JLabel Mph_Label = new JLabel("Enter the wind speed in mph:");
   Mph_Label.setForeground(new Color(255, 140, 0));
   Mph_Label.setBounds(10, 123, 305, 14);
   panel.add(Mph_Label);

   Mph_textField = new JTextField();
   Mph_textField.setColumns(10);
   Mph_textField.setBounds(338, 120, 86, 20);
   Mph_textField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
   panel.add(Mph_textField);

   JLabel DewPoint_Label = new JLabel("Enter the dew point in degrees Fahrenheit:");
   DewPoint_Label.setForeground(new Color(255, 140, 0));
   DewPoint_Label.setBounds(10, 177, 305, 14);
   panel.add(DewPoint_Label);

   DewPoint_textField = new JTextField();
   DewPoint_textField.setColumns(10);
   DewPoint_textField.setBounds(338, 174, 86, 20);
   DewPoint_textField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
   panel.add(DewPoint_textField);

   JButton FileEntry_btn = new JButton("File Entry");
   FileEntry_btn.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
   FileEntry_btn.setForeground(new Color(255, 140, 0));
   FileEntry_btn.setBounds(39, 283, 89, 23);
   panel.add(FileEntry_btn);

   JButton Compute_btn = new JButton("Compute");
   Compute_btn.setForeground(new Color(255, 140, 0));
   Compute_btn.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
   Compute_btn.setBounds(301, 283, 89, 23);
   panel.add(Compute_btn);

   Compute_btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           WeatherOutput output = new WeatherOutput();
           output.setVisible(true);
       }
   });
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this answer will satisfy the OP.  I hope others will learn from it.

Here are the changes I made to the code.

1. I used a `JFrame`.  I didn't extend a `JFrame`.  You only extend a Swing component, or any Java class, when you want to override one of the class methods.
2. I created the GUI and gave the user a chance to type values before I calculated the wind speed.
3. I eliminated all absolute positioning and used [Swing layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).  I created a master `JPanel` and two subordinate `JPanel`s, one to hold the labels and text fields, and the other to hold the buttons.  The master panel used a `BorderLayout`, the labels and text fields panel used a `GridBagLayout`, and the buttons panel used a `GridBagLayout` so the buttons would expand horizontally to fill the area.
4. I used camelCase variable names in the code.

Here's the GUI result.

[image: GUI]

I formatted the code so it would be easier to see the methods and classes.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class WindChillCalculations {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField fahrenheit_textField;
    private JTextField mph_textField;
    private JTextField dewPoint_textField;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {       
                    new WindChillCalculations();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public WindChillCalculations() {
        // top, left, bottom, right
        Insets topInsets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        Insets topRightInsets = new Insets(10, 0, 10, 10);
        Insets insets = new Insets(0, 10, 10, 10);
        Insets rightInsets = new Insets(0, 0, 10, 10);

        Color textColor = new Color(255, 140, 0);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Weather Data Program - "
                + "Wind Chill Calculations");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JLabel windChillCalculationsLabel = new JLabel(
                "Wind Chill Calculations");
        windChillCalculationsLabel.setFont(new Font(
                "Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        windChillCalculationsLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        windChillCalculationsLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(
                JLabel.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(windChillCalculationsLabel, 
            BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setToolTipText("");
        panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.WHITE));
        panel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        int gridy = 0;

        JLabel fahrenheit_Label = new JLabel("Enter the "
                + "temperature in degrees Fahrenheit:");
        fahrenheit_Label.setForeground(textColor);
        addComponent(panel, fahrenheit_Label, 0, gridy, 1, 1, 
                topInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        fahrenheit_textField = new JTextField(15);
        fahrenheit_textField.setHorizontalAlignment(
                JTextField.RIGHT);
        addComponent(panel, fahrenheit_textField, 1, gridy++, 1, 1, 
                topRightInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JLabel mph_Label = new JLabel("Enter the wind "
                + "speed in mph:");
        mph_Label.setForeground(textColor);
        addComponent(panel, mph_Label, 0, gridy, 1, 1, 
                insets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        mph_textField = new JTextField(15);
        mph_textField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        addComponent(panel, mph_textField, 1, gridy++, 1, 1, 
                rightInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JLabel dewPoint_Label = new JLabel("Enter the "
                + "dew point in degrees Fahrenheit:");
        dewPoint_Label.setForeground(textColor);
        addComponent(panel, dewPoint_Label, 0, gridy, 1, 1, 
                insets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        dewPoint_textField = new JTextField(15);
        dewPoint_textField.setHorizontalAlignment(
                JTextField.RIGHT);
        addComponent(panel, dewPoint_textField, 1, gridy++, 1, 1, 
                rightInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        buttonPanel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JButton fileEntry_btn = new JButton("File Entry");
        fileEntry_btn.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        fileEntry_btn.setForeground(textColor);
        addComponent(buttonPanel, fileEntry_btn, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
                topInsets, GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JButton compute_btn = new JButton("Compute");
        compute_btn.setForeground(textColor);
        compute_btn.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        compute_btn.setBounds(301, 283, 89, 23);
        addComponent(buttonPanel, compute_btn, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
                topRightInsets, GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        compute_btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String fahrenheit = fahrenheit_textField.getText();
                String speed = mph_textField.getText();
                String dewpoint = dewPoint_textField.getText();

                try {
                    double f = Double.valueOf(fahrenheit);
                    double s = Double.valueOf(speed);
                    double d = Double.valueOf(dewpoint);
                    WindChill windChill = new WindChill(f, s, d);
                    double answer = windChill.calculateWindChill();

                    //TODO Create output display
                    System.out.println(answer);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        contentPane.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);

        frame.add(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addComponent(Container container, 
            Component component, int gridx, int gridy, 
            int gridwidth, int gridheight, Insets insets, 
            int anchor, int fill) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(
                gridx, gridy, gridwidth, gridheight, 
                1.0, 1.0, anchor, fill, insets, 0, 0);
        container.add(component, gbc);
    }

    public class WindChill {

        private final double temperature;
        private final double windSpeed;
        private final double dewPoint;

        public WindChill(double temperature, double windSpeed, 
                double dewPoint) {
            this.temperature = temperature;
            this.windSpeed = windSpeed;
            this.dewPoint = dewPoint;
        }

        public double calculateWindChill() {
            double factor = Math.pow(windSpeed, 0.16);
            return 35.74d + (0.6215d * temperature) - 
                    (35.75d * (factor)) + 
                    (0.4275 * (dewPoint * (factor)));
        }

    }
}
```